How do I implement a conditional equality constraint?
I'm implementing a transshipment model in the python module Pyomo where I'm trying to optimise the movement of products that are shipped between suppliers to buyers.
I need to implement a constraint where some supplier - buyer combinations are Not Approved and therefore the volume of the product allocated should be 0.
Any recommendations on how I should implement this? My previous attempts have given rise to an infeasible problem.

You should edit your post and include the code that you have attempted to get better advice.  You basically have 2 choices:  edit your index sets so the "illegal" combinations are not represented in the data, or make a constraint over each of the illegal combinations and force the decision variable to be zero.
